# What is a good way to get back to the command prompt discarding STDOUT and STDERR

Tags: command-line, bash, routing, redirection

I often launch applications from the cli via e.g. `command &` to immediately get back to the prompt back. 
The downside of this is, that I still get STDOUT and STDERR.

So I use `command &> /dev/null` to discard those outputs.

This can get quite a chore, when having to write this often during a day.

So my question is, is there a better (read shorter) way to discard of STDOUT and STDERR when not needed?

What could be done? Maybe write a wrapper script to launch applications? 
What would be an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a function (e.g., in your `.alias`, `.bashrc` file)

```
launch () 
{ 
    "$@" >&/dev/null &
}
```

This can then be used as

```
launch command
```

For example

```
launch xemacs ./myfile.txt
```

Comment: Use `"$@" >&/dev/null &` to avoid problems with spaces, wildcards, etc in the command's arguments.